# (MAC) terminal ok to run command

Tags: macos, command

With the command:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "Press ok to run command"'
```

Is it possible when you press "OK" it will run a command?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's basic bash scripting, add a `&&` plus the command you want to run:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "Press ok to run command"' && echo "run it"
```

replace `echo "run it"` with the command you need

Comment: THX! for your help!